# MySQL: Disallowing two columns from having the same values

Tags: mysql

I currently have a table that keeps track of courses students are taking, have taken.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`course_enrollment` (
`courseID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`studentID` BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`startDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`endDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`semester` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`section` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`courseGrade` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`courseID`) REFERENCES courses(`courseID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`studentID`) REFERENCES students(`studentID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

However, I know I can't have two primary keys in a table. But I want to be able to insert two of the same courseIDs, as long as the semester is different.

Example: (Irrelevant but FA stands for Fall, SP stands for Spring)

```
CourseID:  -- Student ID --   Semester
1            30               FA15
1            30               FA16
2            30               FA16
2            30               SP17
2            31               SP17
But not
1            30               FA18
1            30               FA18
```

The course ID and the Semester cannot have the same exact courseID and Semester duplicate.

If I make the semester a unique index, then I can't assign the same semester to multiple courses.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create unique composite key so that the combination of two are unique.

```
ALTER TABLE `course_enrollment` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(studentID,`courseID`,`semester`);
```

Edit:- Added studentId also in unique constraint as for each studentID , courseId and semester must be unique.

Comment: This would mean that 2 students would not be able to enroll to the same course in the same semester.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to add that information. Thanks Shadow!

Comment: This should actually be the primary key of the table.  A table only has one primary key, but that key can be multi-column, and in this case, it should.

Answer (score 0):

Create a multiple-column index in this case. I would think that you can't have the same student enrolling to the same course in the same semester, so I would create a unique index on these 3 fields. See mysql documentation on [multiple column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).